# Rails multiple has many relationships on the same model, one with an alias and polymorphic

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have two models, a `User` model and a `Task` model.  Prior to setting up the new relationship, there was a simple `has_many` and `belongs_to` relationship, ex:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

This relationship in my application really represents the user that created the task record, for example when a user creates one it sets the current user's id equal to the `tasks.user_id`.

I also want another relationship (the same exact type) for an "assigned" feature.  What this means is that the relationship above represents the creator of the task, while the `assigned_id` represents who it is assigned to.

However, the `assigned_id` can be a `User`, `Vendor`, or `Carrier`.  Hence the polymorphic relationship.  I've set this up on my `Task` model and it now has an `assignable_id` and an `assignable_type` column on it in the database.

I added this to my `Task` model: `belongs_to :assignable, :polymorphic => true`.

What line can I add to make this association work in the `User` model.  There already is the `has_many :tasks` but this is for a different purpose.  How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below:

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: 'Task', as: :assignable
```

Comment: That worked, thanks!  Will accept as answer when time limit is up.